# ld: library not found for -lAmplitude when lib exists at .../BuildProductsPath/Debug-iphoneos/Amplitude

Tags: ios, react-native, cocoapods, xcodebuild, amplitude-analytics

I keep getting this error when building my app using `xcodebuild` from the command line.

```
xcodebuild -workspace ios/APP_NAME.xcworkspace -scheme APP_NAME clean archive -sdk iphoneos -configuration Debug -UseModernBuildSystem=NO -archivePath $PWD/APP_NAME CODE_SIGNING_ALLOWED=NO;
```

The app builds fine via Xcode UI. This is a react native app, and I tried a bunch of things listed here - [Xcode - ld: library not found for -lPods](https://stackoverflow.com/Questions/23539147/xcode-ld-Library-not-found-for-lpods), that didn't work.

- Setting same deployment target for Pods and App projects
- Deleting `libAmplitude.a` from app project's Frameworks folder
- Setting `Build Active Architecture Only` to NO
- Embedding `libAmplitude.a` along with `libPods-APP_NAME.a`

Strangely the file it can't find actually exists in the directory. I see two failures of this type (arm64, armv7).

```
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L-L/Users/Parth/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/APP_NAME-atzumsqdaojeyaaukpzreucvvlja/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/APP_NAME/BuildProductsPath/Debug-iphoneos/Amplitude'
ld: library not found for -lAmplitude
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Final build failure:

```
The following build commands failed:
        Ld /Users/Parth/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/APP_NAME-atzumsqdaojeyaaukpzreucvvlja/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/APP_NAME/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/APP_NAME.build/Debug-iphoneos/APP_NAME.build/Objects-normal/arm64/APP_NAME normal arm64
        Ld /Users/Parth/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/APP_NAME-atzumsqdaojeyaaukpzreucvvlja/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/APP_NAME/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/APP_NAME.build/Debug-iphoneos/APP_NAME.build/Objects-normal/armv7/APP_NAME normal armv7
(2 failures)
```

> Issue filed with amplitude - https://github.com/amplitude/Amplitude-ReactNative/issues/87

### Edit

This might be the root cause of the problem, after changing `other linker flags` to `${inherited}`, I see 2 mentions for Amplitude.

1. -l"Amplitude"
2. -l"amplitude-react-native"

[image: linker flags]

Answer (score 0):

I got this working after changing this setting `-UseModernBuildSystem=YES`.

```
xcodebuild -workspace ios/APP_NAME.xcworkspace -scheme APP_NAME clean archive -sdk iphoneos -configuration Debug -UseModernBuildSystem=YES -archivePath $PWD/APP_NAME CODE_SIGNING_ALLOWED=NO;
```

I also had to:

1. Update minimum support to iOS 11
2. Set linker flags to *ONLY* `${inhereted}`
3. Set `Build Active Architecture Only` to `YES`.